# C# P/Invoke Corrupt Memory

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I have a weird issue with C# P/Invoke where a struct is corrupt when marshalling from C# to C++ unless passing the struct by ref but doesn't happen with all other structs in the same call and other calls.

The first call works 100% no issues, even with an array. The second calls works only when I pass Struct8 as ref, if I don't then the memory is corrupt by the time it hits the C++ code which doesn't make sense as why would all the other structures work without having to pass by reference?

My structures are 1:1 (string to char with MarshalAs etc.)
The C++ code does C-Style arrays for the most part

I am making the following calls

```
var struct1 = new Struct1() { Name = @"TEST" };
Create(
    struct1,
    ref struct2,
    new Struct3() { Channel = string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Channel) ? "TESTCHANNEL" : request.Channel },
    Array.Empty<Struct4>(),
    new Struct5() { Something = 0 },
    out var struct6,
    out var struct7,
    out var struct2Detail
);

var struct8 = new Struct8() { Number = struct2.Number, TrySomething = 1 };
Initialize(struct1, struct8, out struct6, out struct2Detail);
```

Only works when I call it like this:

```
Initialize(struct1, ref struct8, out struct6, out struct2Detail);
```

Pseudo code for C# Marshalling + Structs

```
public static void Create(
    Struct1 struct1
    ,ref Struct2 struct2
    ,Struct3 struct3
    ,Struct4[] struct4
    ,Struct5 struct5
    ,out Struct6 struct6
    ,out Struct7 struct7
    ,out Struct2Detail struct2Detail
)
{
    int numProcFields = struct4.Length;
    Net5_Create(
        struct1
        ,ref struct2
        ,struct3
        ,ref numProcFields
        ,struct4
        ,struct5
        ,out struct6
        ,out struct7
        ,out struct2Detail
    );
}

[DllImport(LIBNAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Net5_Create(
    Struct1 struct1
    ,[In, Out] ref Struct2 struct2
    ,Struct3 struct3
    ,[In, Out] ref int numProcFields
    ,Struct4[] struct4
    ,Struct5 struct5
    ,out Struct6 struct6
    ,out Struct7 struct7
    ,out Struct2Detail struct2Detail
);

public static void Initialize(
    Struct1 struct1
    ,Struct8 struct8
    ,out Struct6 struct6
    ,out Struct2Detail struct2Detail
)
{
    Net5_Initialize(
        struct1
        ,struct8
        ,out struct6
        ,out struct2Detail
    );
}

[DllImport(LIBNAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Net5_Initialize(
    Struct1 struct1
    ,Struct8 struct8
    ,out Struct6 struct6
    ,out Struct2Detail struct2Detail
);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Struct1
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 33)]
    public string Name;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Struct2
{
    public int Number;
    public int Reference;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 65)]
    public string ReferenceValue;
    public int ReferenceYear;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string DateCreated;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Struct4
{
    public int ObjectType;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 65)]
    public string Name;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 201)]
    public string Value;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Struct6
{
    public int Number1;
    public int Number2;
    public int Number3;
    public int Number4;
    public int Number5;
    public int Number6;
    public int Number7;
    public int Number8;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Struct7
{
    public int Number1;
    public int Number2;
    public int Number3;
    public int Number4;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 65)]
    public string String1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 257)]
    public string String2;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Struct8
{
    public int Number;
    public int TrySomething;
}
```

Code on the C++ side

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#ifdef _WIN32
#    define MODULE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define MODULE_API
#endif

MODULE_API void Net5_Initialize(
    Struct1* struct1
    ,Struct8* struct8
    ,Struct6* struct6
    ,Struct2Detail* struct2Detail
);

void Net5_Initialize(
        Struct1* struct1
        ,Struct8* struct8
        ,Struct6* struct6
        ,Struct2Detail* struct2Detail
    )
{
    dotnetInstance->Initialize(
         struct1
        , struct8
        , struct6
        , struct2Detail
    );
}
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif

// typedef __int32 int32;
struct Struct1
{
    char Name[33];
    Struct1()
    {
        Name[0] = 0;
    }
    void Function1() { ... }
}

struct Struct2
{
    int32 Number;
    int32 Reference;
    char ReferenceValue[65];
    int32 ReferenceYear;
    char DateCreated[16];
    Struct2()
    {
        Number = 0;
        Reference = 0;
        ReferenceValue[0] = 0;
        ReferenceYear = 0;
        DateCreated[0] = 0;
    }
    void Function1() { ... }
}

struct Struct4
{
    int32 ObjectType;
    char Name[65];
    char Value[201];
    Struct4()
    {
        ObjectType = 0;
        Name[0] = 0;
        Value[0] = 0;
    }
    void Function1() { ... }
}

struct Struct6
{
    int32 Number1;
    int32 Number2;
    int32 Number3;
    int32 Number4;
    int32 Number5;
    int32 Number6;
    int32 Number7;
    int32 Number8;
    Struct6()
    {
        Number1 = 0;
        Number2 = 0;
        Number3 = 0;
        Number4 = 0;
        Number5 = 0;
        Number6 = 0;
        Number7 = 0;
        Number8 = 0;
    }
    void Function1() { ... }
}

struct Struct7
{
    int32 Number1;
    int32 Number2;
    int32 Number3;
    int32 Number4;
    char String1[65]
    char String2[257];
    Struct7()
    {
        Number1 = 0;
        Number2 = 0;
        Number3 = 0;
        Number4 = 0;
        String1[0] = 0;
        String2[0] = 0;
    }
    void Function1() { ... }
}
struct Struct8
{
  int32 Number;
  int32 TrySomething;
  Struct8()
  {
    Number = 0;
    TrySomething = 0;
  }
    void Function1() { ... }
}
void Class::Create(Struct1* struct1, Struct2* struct2, Struct3* struct3, int32* numProcFields, Struct4* struct4, Struct5* struct5, Struct6* struct6, Struct7* struct7, Struct2Detail* struct2Detail)
{
    ...
}
void Class::Initialize(Struct1* struct1, Struct8* struct8, Struct6* struct6, Struct2Detail* struct2Detail)
{
    lprintf("Initialize - Started (%d)", struct8->Number);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Without looking too deeply... `Struct1` is passed as a pointer on the C++ side, but passed by value on the C# side.

Comment: addition to canton7 comment: size of `Struct1` is the same as size of pointer (as it's only contains pointer to string) thats why there is no problem with sending Struct1 by val not by ref (but still it's wrong)

Comment: If I change all the structs to by ref then I get other issues with the heap getting corrupt when the functions return

Comment: out usage is also wrong ... it rather should be used when native side expect pointer to pointer, please show `Initialize` on native side as `Class::Initialize` is not what is used here (it's class member  so obviously it's using `thiscall` not `cdecl`)

Comment: Sure. I have edited the question. It's just a proxy as there's a global instance for the class. Added header code and impl code as one but they are in different files

Comment: Changed everything now to byref again then I get this:
```Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDC86AF199 (ntdll.dll) in app.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x00007FFDC87177F0).
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFDC86AF199 (ntdll.dll) in app.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x00007FFDC87177F0).```

Comment: `ref` is definitely correct. What are the struct definitions in C++

Comment: all parameter should have `ref` not `out` with `StructX* struct` parameter on C side library is expecting pointer to allocated memory with size of `StructX` ...

Comment: with `out StructX struct` on C# side you are passing there  `StructX** struct = NULL;` which would be only valid if C side would do something like `*struct = new StructX;`

Comment: also C code compiled with `/Gz` would make it  `stdcall` rather then `cdecl` - it is better to set calling convetion on C side rather then rely on defaults

Comment: I have updated question to reflect the C structs as well. As I say, I started with ref for everything and I have re-changed everything to be byref now as well and not out just then I get those heap corruptions. The C code does not do new's on those pointers from a quick glance at the top level (but it is still possible as it's a large api so somewhere down in the bowels it is possible).

Comment: Whether they're in, out, or in+out, define all structs in C# as `ref MyStruct myStruct` (note this implicitly means in+out, no need to add [In, Out] etc.). And make sure the calling convention is consistent. This is the easiest way to go.

Comment: The API is very old and we are in the process of rewriting it to be pure Dotnet 5 but I still have to reference it as if it's in C until such time so I can't change the C layer too much. And it's compiled with __cdecl (/Gd)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out the problem wasn't with Initialize, it was stomping over the input array's memory of Create if that one is also byref

Working Create

```
[DllImport(LIBNAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Net5_Create(
    ref Struct1 struct1
    ,ref Struct2 struct2
    ,ref Struct3 struct3
    ,ref int numProcFields
    ,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] Struct4[] struct4
    ,ref Struct5 struct5
    ,ref Struct6 struct6
    ,ref Struct7 struct7
    ,ref Struct2Detail struct2Detail
);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you would add `ref` to the array and do not use attribute this should also work...

Comment: @selvin no it would not